# Trying to check size of some cin statement

Tags: size, cin

I have some simple user input function which reads what the user types, ignoring any enter's and taking the first character it comes across. I am using the cin.ignore statement because this is part of a menu, and I want to replay the menu if they enter none of the given options, but only once. Now I basically want to have an if-statement which is true iff the user entered only one character (he may enter multiple enter's before this character), so I wanted to use something like sizeof or length, but I couldn't quite get it to work. Can anybody help with this? It would be much appreciated. Also, if anything should be changed about the phrasing of the question, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
char Interface::leesin ( ) {
char invoer;
do {
    invoer = cin.get();
} while (invoer == '\n');
cin.ignore(MAX,'\n');
return invoer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following is a code snippet whereby the user will be presented with a console menu and needs to input a character. The cin will read in only 1 char and then the program can do some processing with this char. The loop will terminate, when the user inputs the char '9'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char ch;

    do {
      //print menu here

      cin >> ch; // take in one char only

      //perform action based on ch

    } while (ch != '9');


   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer so that other users can ready understand your code.